# validating proposal: access denied: channel [] creator org unknown, creator is malformed)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm building a network of three orderers, four organizations, one peer for each organization, and I can create channel, but I get the following error when I add the organization's peer to the channel:
“Error: proposal failed (err: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = error validating proposal: access denied: channel [] creator org unknown, creator is malformed)”, How can I solve this problem?

I can't find a solution for this.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I am getting the same issue.

Comment: this is an issue with the newer version of the fabric.
facing the same issue. I don't know the cause yet.

Comment: Have you got solution to this? I am encountering same issues.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue for me. All works good on 2.4.8 but, upgrading to 2.5.4, after every peer command i had the same problem. Solved setting the environement var in the peer yaml:

```html
- CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp (check the path for your configuration)
```

and recreating the peer container all works good for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing this error while executing a CLI command which communicates with orderer, then single/double quotes on `CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID` environment variable can be an issue [as discussed here.](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/issues/4358#ref-issue-2005984548)

```bash
# before
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org1MSP"
# after
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
```

Make sure to remove quotes on client environment variable values and try again.